# Unable to iterate through String created with Gson

Tags: java, json, string, android, gson

I am trying to iterate through this String that I created using Gson.

```
"`{\"public_id\":\"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp\":xxxxx,\"signature\":\"xxxxx\",\"api_key\":\"xxxxxx\"}"`
```

I have tried making this string into a JSONArray and iterating it with Iterator but got `of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

This is how I am constructing my String

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String parameter = gson.toJson(newImages.get(i).post_data);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to iterate through the string to eventually add these properties into an okhttp request.

Comment: That makes no sense. First this JSON is an object, not an array. Second, you can't iterate through a String. A String is not a collection. Third, if you want to access individual properties of the object, why do you transform it to a JSON string in the first place. Just use the object `newImages.get(i).post_data` directly.

Comment: Your json looks like it has been escaped by the client (the quotes are escaped: `\"` and it's wrapped in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I really can't tell what you are doing, but using gson.toJson() isn't helping. I don't know what post_data is, but it looks like a String, and toJson() seems to be wrapping it in quotes and escaping the quotes inside.

I *think* what you want to do is to parse post_data. *Possibly*, post_data is JSON. If so, use gson.fromJson() to parse it into an object. Note that you will have to define the target object with fields that match the JSON structure.